# What kind space does spinor lives in?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, representation-theory, topology, spinors

I'm trying to read some differential geometry these days and I just encountered orientable manifold.

Quote: "If $M$ is nonorientable, $M$ has a two-sheeted orientable covering manifold $\tilde{M}$. If $M$ is simply connected, then $M$ is orientable."

I heard my instructor talking during the class couple of days before where he mentioned the spin/spinor lives in a spaces of two copy.

Question 1: what does orientable manifold has to do with spinor?

Question 2: what kind of space does spinor lives in? as it seemed to imply that every spinor got a "hold" or singular value inside of them.

Comment: why here and not math.SE?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don't think math people do spinor or electron like that in physics.

Comment: When you ask “what kind of space”, what kind of explanation do you want? Spinor space is a linear vector space that acts as a *representation space* in the sense of group representation theory. It is not a geometric space like spacetime.

Comment: What do you mean by “hold”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1: what does orientable manifold has to do with spinor?

Spinor fields cannot be consistently defined on an arbitrary manifold. As the Encyclopedia of Mathematics [explains](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Spinor_structure), “Necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a spinor structure on $M$  consist of the orientability of $M$ and the vanishing of the Stiefel–Whitney class $W_2(M)$.

(To understand what a Stiefel-Whitney class is, take a course in algebraic topology or ask on Math SE.)

> Question 2: what kind of space does spinor lives in?

Spinor space is a complex linear vector space that acts as a *representation space* for the Poincaré group in the sense of [group representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory). It is not a geometric space like spacetime on which fields are defined; it is a space in which certain fermion fields have their *values*. Instead of having four *real* dimensions like spacetime, spinor space has two or four *complex* dimensions.

A Poincaré transformation of spacetime coordinates makes the spinor field at each point change its “length” and “direction” in the spinor space. Suppose transformation $A$ in spacetime followed by transformation $B$ is equivalent to a single transformation $C$. Then the transformation $A’$ in spinor space corresponding to $A$, followed by the transformation $B’$ corresponding to $B$, must be equivalent to the single transformation $C’$ corresponding to $C$. In other words, the transformations of field values in spinor space are [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) to the transformations of coordinates in spacetime. Both “represent” the same abstract group composition law, on two completely different spaces!

Comment: I'm trying to grasp the best understanding of spinors as possible. One way that I'm feel more or less confortable is to see them as sections of a bundle: the spinor bundle, which is a associated with a principal bundle. In this sense spinors (fields) are just sections of a bundle. Now, probably this answer is something prior to bundle theory in a sense of the definition of the spinor object and not a spinor field. Moreover, I would say that the spinor bundle is a very geometrical space . But yes, it is not the spacetime per se. [1]

[1] Mark Hamilton "Mathematical Gauge theory".